# Getting error for passing default values to the null fields using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have small requiment, here I'm getting values to the table dynamically. Some times few fields returns some null/blank values. If it gives null values showing error message like  `"worderId[i].childNodes[0] is undefined"`
    Please help me  how to assign some default values to the null values.

```
if(worderId.length>0)
{

WOTableData= "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1' border='0' width=100% class='display' id='WOData' ><thead><tr id='row1'><th>&nbsp;</th><th>worderId</th><th>wostatus</th></thead><tbody>";
var technologyImage="";
for(i=0;i<worderId.length;i++)
    {   

        if (!worderId[i].childNodes || !worderId[i].childNodes.length || !worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
                 worderId[i].childNodes =="---";
        }

        WOTableData=WOTableData+"<tr title='"+worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+ worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+wostatus[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";                                            

    }
WOTableData=WOTableData+"</tbody></table>";


document.getElementById("WODataDiv").innerHTML = WOTableData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand this piece of your code

```
 if (!worderId[i].childNodes || !worderId[i].childNodes.length || !worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
             worderId[i].childNodes =="---";
    }

    WOTableData=WOTableData+"<tr title='"+worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+ worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+wostatus[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";
```

You are checking if **worderId[i].childNodes** does not exist or if it does and assuming it is an array, it has at least, one element or the first element of that array has a key named **nodeValue**. If either of these conditions are true, you assign

```
   worderId[i].childNodes =="---";
```

So now worderId[i].childNodes is a string. Then you access

```
  WOTableData=WOTableData+"<tr title='"+worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+ worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+wostatus[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";
```

**worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue** will give you an error in case any of the above conditions were true as in that case, you have assigned the value of **worderId[i].childNodes** as string and it is not an array.

So, to fix it you could do this

```
  var assignValue = "";
  if (!worderId[i].childNodes || !worderId[i].childNodes.length || !worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
            assignValue =  worderId[i].childNodes =="---";
    }else{
        assignValue = worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }

    WOTableData=WOTableData+"<tr title='"+assignValue+"</td><td>"+ assignValue+"</td><td>"+assignValue+"</td></tr>";
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for explanations, I fixed my issue.

Comment: @Rajasekhar Glad it helped!